# How to assign Nth value of an array to variable

Tags: java

I have an array of Values. With the use of a random number generator I get the nth value of the array Values. How can I assign this Value to a variable since I need to do some calculations.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  //int c=0;
  Integer[] Values = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
   Random rand = new Random(); 
   int n;
  for (int c=1; c<=12; c++){

   n = rand.nextInt(5); 
   System.out.println(Values[n]);
   System.out.println(c);


  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = rand.nextInt(5);
int randNum = Values[n];
//your calculations with randNum go here
```